# wrap extension output with typoscript typo3 is not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I'm using Typo3 7.6.4 and I want to wrap an extension output with a div.

The extension is `csv-table`.

How can I do this with Typoscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a fluid layout if you use EXT:fluid_styled_content

Resources/Private/Templates/CsvTable.html

```
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="Main">
  my output
</f:section>
```

Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html

```
<div class="my-element">
  <f:render section="Main" />
</div>
```

[TypoScript reference: FLUIDTEMPLATE](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html)

If you use the old css_styled_content you can use this

```
tt_content.my_ext = COA
tt_content.my_ext.stdWrap.wrap = <div>|</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Most plug-ins are defined as a `USER` or `USER_INT` objects. These have a property `stdWrap` [See TypoScript Reference - USER(_INT)](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html#stdwrap)
I couldn't find the extension 'csv-table' for TYPO3 7, but let's assume that it's available in TypoScript as `plugin.tx_csvtable_pi1` then you could use something like:

```
plugin.tx_csvtable_pi1.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="myCsvTable">|</div>
```